# How is Nothing a subtype of every other type in Scala

Tags: programming-languages, scala

I am taking Martin Odersky's coursera course on functional programming with scala, and for now I have learned two things that together don't make sense:

1. Scala doesn't support multiple inheritance
2. `Nothing` is a subtype of every other type

These two statements cannot live together, so how exactly is this done? and what exactly is the meaning of "subtype of every other type"

**Edit 1**

In the [Scala API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Nothing), `Nothing` is defined as `abstract final class Nothing extends Any`... so how can it extend other classes?

Comment: This page might help a bit: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/scalas-hierarchy.html

Comment: As far as I can see it is defined as "final trait Nothing
extends Any"

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.6/scala/Nothing.html

Comment: It appears that Scala compiler is open source. Have you checked it already?

Comment: You are confusing types and classes. Those two are very different things. Unfortunately, you are not the only one who is confused by that distinction, and *really* unfortunately, some of those who are confused happen to be the designers of popular languages like Java, C# and C++. It doesn't say that `Nothing` is a subclass of every other class. It says that it is a *subtype* of every other *type*.

Comment: @JörgWMittag The designers of Java and C# know that as they put interfaces in the respective languages. And the designers of C++ know that as C++ has numerous types which aren't classes. Now, many *users* of those languages confuse the two, but it's safe to say the designers are aware that `Class` is a subtype of `Type`.

Comment: @delnan: Java's interfaces are taken directly from Smalltalk's protocols. In Smalltalk, only protocols are types, classes aren't. In Java, *both* interfaces *and* classes are types. That's wrong. Classes aren't types, only interfaces are. The fact that all of these languages have things that are types and not classes is irrelevant. The problem is that in those languages classes are types, which is wrong.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That's a different statement, and extremely arguable (I tend to agree that it's harmful, but I would not attribute this to a misunderstanding of typing). No point in discussing it here.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Subtyping and inheritance are two different things! `Nothing` doesn't *extend* everything, it's a *subtype*, it only extends `Any`.

The [specification<sup>[§3.5.2]</sup>](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) has a special case governing the subtyping-relationship of `Nothing`:

> §3.5.2 Conformance
>
> - [...]
> - For every value type
>     `T` , `scala.Nothing <: T <:scala.Any`
> - For every type constructor `T` (with any number of type parameters)
>     `scala.Nothing <: T <: scala.Any`
> - [...]

Where `<:` basically means "is a subtype of".

As for how this is done: We don't know, it's compiler magic and an implementation detail.

Quite often a language does things you as a programmer can't. As a counterpart to `Nothing`: Everything in Scala inherits from `Any`, everything *except* `Any`. Why doesn't `Any` inherit from something? You can't do that. Why can Scala do that? Well, because Scala set the rules, not you. `Nothing` being a subtype of everything is just an other instance of this.

Comment: BTW: this is exactly the same as `null` being assignable to a field of every type in Java. Why is that possible? Is `null` an instance of every class? No, it is possible because the compiler says so. Period.

Comment: If I could upvote this a hundred times, I would. Confusing *types* and *classes* is one of the worst things languages like Java have brought upon us.

Comment: For curious souls about difference between inheritance and subtypes http://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/courses/pl2006/lecturenotes/lecture-notes/node28.html however I don't buy it -- if you inherit (like `extends` in Java, and not as compose) you do it for subtyping after all.

Answer (score 12):

When he says that Scala doesn't support multiple inheritance, then he refers to inheriting a method implementation multiple times. Of course, you can implement multiple interfaces/traits in a class, and they can even define the same method, but you do not get a conflict between the different implementations due to trait linearization.

In general, if you have a class `C1` with a method `f()` and a class `C2` also with a method `f()`, then multiple inheritance means you can somehow inherit both implementations of `f()`. This can lead to various problems, which Scala resolves by only letting you inherit from a single class and in case of multiple traits by selecting one implementation based on the order of the traits.

As for `Nothing` things are really simple, because nothing has no attributes or methods defined. So you cannot have any inheritance conflicts. But I assume that most of your surprise comes from a different understanding of multiple inheritance.

Once you understand that trait linearization effectively eliminates any ambiguity of the inheritance, and that we do not refer to inheriting from multiple traits as *multiple inheritance* due to that, then you should be fine.

As to how this is realized: the compiler is eventually responsible for this. See the [Scala language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) section 3.5.2 conformance, which amongst other properties includes:

```
For every type constructor T (with any number of type parameters), scala.Nothing <: T <: scala.Any.
```

Or in other words, if you want to implement a compiler correctly, it has to handle `Nothing` as a subtype of everything by specification. For obvious reasons, `Nothing` is not defined to extend from all classes loaded into the system, but the relevance of defining `Nothing` as subtype is limited to all places, where subtyping is relevant.

An important point here is that there exists no instance of type `Nothing`, hence, its treatment is strictly limited to type-checking, which is all in the realm of the compiler.

Comment: What I still don't understand is how this is done... See the edit to my question

Comment: "the relevance of defining Nothing as subtype is limited to all places, where subtyping is relevant." What do you want to convey with that? X is relevant where X is relevant?